# What value is usually assigned to the initial value. Can anyone provide an example?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

```
// ignore_for_file: use_key_in_widget_constructors

import 'package:flutter_firebase/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_firebase/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<NewUser>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: [],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what value to use for initial data or any alternative. The tutorial I am following uses an older version of flutter and its not necessary. But in the new version it is mandatory. Thanks

Comment: Usually and empty value like here. I would say when building the children have a widget build for empty values so the user knows that it's the initial value or an empty value

Comment: @Apealed it asks for a NewUser instance in the initial value and it can't be null.

Comment: I never said to put null. Put an empty value.

Comment: Yeah it worked Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should mention the **type for StreamProvider** as

```
StreamProvider<List<NewUser>>
```

If your 'NewUser' is a List.

Or you should explicitly mention the type there. (Usually List is used)